# Conditional Column: Order of Tests Matters?

Tags: excel, powerquery

## Condition to Test Date

I am using Power Query to create a status column that checks the date against a specified date, like so:

[image: Initial query logic]

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Logical.
Details:
    Value=
    Type=[Type]
```

The column does contain empty cells, which I want to report as "null" in the new column. I then tried the following logic, and it errors out as well:

[image: Second query logic]

Then I moved the null test to the top, and it finally works:

[image: Working query logic]

## Why Does Order Matter?

Why does the third query produce the expected results but not the first one? This seems bizarre to me, so if there is something I am missing please let me know.

Comment: you can also wrap your formula in try ... otherwise .., but @david has the real answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Better Understanding of NULLs

I was not understanding how Excel (or any other data tool) handles null values and how logical tests are performed on null values. This response on Reddit really helped clarify this in my mind:

https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/xu37dr/comment/iqtmivn/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

In short, logical tests involving nulls do not behave like you would expect.

For a deeper dive into this, read this excellent post:

https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2018/09/13/4617/power-query-m-primer-part9-types-logical-null-binary

## My Solution

Given this enlightened understanding of nulls and how they behave in logical tests, I now know that I must either:

1. Convert the null values to empty strings (`""`) before the query
2. Test first for nulls in the query

My choice is to test for nulls first within the query, like so:

[image: Final query]

Answer (score 0):

M is using lazy evaluation in the if statement. If the first statement is true, then it doesn't even bother evaluating the other conditions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-introduction

> For computer language theorists: the formula language specified in
> this document is a mostly pure, higher-order, dynamically typed,
> partially lazy functional language.

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy fix

On a step before your filter, choose "remove nulls" or "replace nulls with values"

#### using `catch`

If you want more flexibility, you can use a `try + catch` pair.
Step `FirstTry` is meant to; be your filter, then I added two ways to handle errors.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromList(sample, Splitter.SplitByNothing(),
        type table[Date = nullable date], null, ExtraValues.Error),

    sample = {
        #date(2020, 1, 1),
        "text", null,
        #date(2024, 1, 1)
    },
    filter = #date(2022, 1, 1),

    FirstTry = Table.AddColumn(
        Source , "Comparison", each filter > [Date], Logical.Type),

    WithFallback = Table.AddColumn(FirstTry, "WithFallback",
        each try
            filter > [Date]
            catch (e) => e[Message], type text),
    
    WithPreservedDatatype = Table.AddColumn(WithFallback, "PreserveColumnType",
        each try
            filter > [Date]
            catch (e) => null meta [ Reason = e[Message] ],
            type logical)
in
    WithPreservedDatatype
```

---

#### things to note

- the query steps are "out of order", which is totally valid. ( above `sample` was referenced "before" its line )
- [Errors are propagated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-error-handling#raising-errors) so an error on step4 could actually be step2. Just keep going up until you find it.
- the `schema` says column `[Date]` is type `date` -- but it's actually `type any`.

What you need is to call `Table.TransformColumnTypes` to **convert and assert datatypes**

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes( Source,{{"Date", type date}})
```

Now row `2` will correctly show an error, because `text` couldn't convert into a `date`